Java Maven Postgres - No Suitable Driver found only in built .jar
I'm currently writing an application that requires a postgres connection. Writing and testing the code in IntelliJ works perfectly. Once the .jar is built I get the No Suitable Driver Found
Now I have checked to see if the package is included in the build using 7zip and I can see the postgresql library there which is what I would expect.
Below is my project pom.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.app.app</groupId>
<artifactId>trac</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Code for the database connection is below. As stated, works perfectly running the app in the IDE.
package com.app.app.db;

import lombok.Getter;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseSession {

   @Getter
   private static Connection connection;

   public static void Initialise(String uri, String user, String password) {
       try {
           Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
           System.out.println("Loaded PostgreSQL JDBC Driver");
           try {
               System.out.println("Attempting to connect to PostgreSQL database..." + uri + " " + user);
               connection = DriverManager.getConnection(uri, user, password);
               if (connection != null) {
                   System.out.println("Successfully connected to PostgreSQL database: " + connection.getSchema());
               }
           } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("Class not found " + e);
       }
    }
}

I'm currently building the jar using IntelliJ's built build tools. I have also tried building with mvn clean followed by mvn package. And have tried Maven Shade as I read that has worked for others.

You tell everything but the most important: how do you assemble and run your application? And i wonder why people still insist on that Class.forName crap, this is obsolete for 10 or so years now.

So I'm using IntelliJ to build the jar. I have also tried using mvn clean followed by mvn package. I have also tried using maven shade as I read that may fix things no luck. The same for the Class.forName line, I did not originally have that but something that was added as I read somewhere it could work. Updated question to reflect this.

@GyroGearless It is not always useless, for one in some situations (e.g. driver in a WAR instead of in the application server), it is actually required to be able to load the driver, because drivers are loaded automatically only once, and if this happened in the AS, then drivers in a WAR will not be found (and if it happens in a WAR, then drivers in other WARs are not loaded), and additionally it provides debugging information like whether the driver is actually found and loaded.

Your executable JAR file needs to include a Class-Path attribute in its MANIFEST.MF file that gives the path to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver JAR file. Does it?

You can check the builded jar file what it contains, your maven dependencies are represented or missing.
Your IDE is collecting dependencies from pom.xml, project settings, classpath, etc, but your builded jar only contains itself, that is why your jar is missing artifacts. You can also check, You wont add some dependncy via the IDE but not from the pom.xml. (but as You write the missing dependency is in your pom.xml, but by the way it is good to know)
You can use a lot of maven plugins for dependency copy.
Here is one of them:
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <useBaseVersion>false</useBaseVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


I did state in the question that the dependencies can be seen in the build.

runtime
Try remove the scope tag it all from the postgresql dependency.  It wont be compiled, so I guess there isnt in your jar's classpath

I've tried the above but no luck. I can see the target folder full of the dependencies etc but still getting the same issue.
